# Move element to viewport when is active

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

I have a horizontal menu with buttons, on mobile you can drag and move left or right to see all elements. When you click on the button it becomes the 'active' button, I add some styling.
What I would achieve here is that when some clicks on a button, it will automatically move to the left or right and become fully visible.

[image: buttons]

as you can see button on the right side is active but it is out of the viewport

I'm looking for ideas on how I could implement such a mechanism in React/Typescript with Emotion

this is a wrapper/container of buttons:

```
const StyledDiv = withTheme(
  styled.div<StyledProps>`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: auto
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    column-gap: 8px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
   }
  `
)
```

this is how button is built itself

```
  return (
    <Button data-label={label} isActive={isActive} onClick={() => setActiveCategory(cat)}>
      { renderIcon(icon) }
      <Wrapper>
        {label}
        <StyledSpan isActive={isActive}>{label}</StyledSpan>
      </Wrapper>
    </Button>
  )
```

and here are CSS code for button

```
const Button = withTheme(
  styled.button<ActiveButtonProps>`
    padding: 4px 16px 4px 8px;
    font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontFamily.sora};
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.horizontalBar.color};
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px ${({ theme }) => theme.horizontalBar.boxShadow};
    outline: none;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.horizontalBar.bgColor};
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 52px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: ${ props => props.isActive ? `1px solid ${color.primary.powerGreen}` : `1px solid transparent`};
    & > img {
      margin-right: 4px; 
    }
  `
)

const StyledSpan = withTheme(
  styled.span<ActiveButtonProps>`
    font-weight: ${ props => props.isActive ? 700 : 400 };
    color: ${ props => props.isActive ? ({ theme }) => theme.horizontalBar.color : ({ theme }) => theme.horizontalBar.colorInactive };
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  `
)

const Wrapper = withTheme(
  styled.p<StyledProps>`
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    color: transparent;
  `
)
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, for example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: @NishargShah as you wish :)